# Protobuf with NodeJS on Windows

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, protocol-buffers

I would like to send simple TCP message to a device (Karotz) from NodeJS Script on Windows.

- NodeJS correctly installed an working
- TCP connection working
- Here is my .proto file (http://wiki.karotz.com/index.php/Voos-message.proto)
- I compile it to .desc using google's protoc

I don't know how to build my message to send it to the device ?

- I read [Google Description](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)
- And [protobuff_for_node](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-for-node/) and other fork

But I don't understand how to install it on windows. Seems complicated because of native librarie.

Is there dead simple javascript librarie that read the .desc Schema and build the message ? Without native code or complicated stuff ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Node.js it's simpler to just use the NPM package version of the protobuf library it'll build it for you, assuming you have a C++ compiler on your machine:

```
> npm install protobuf
```

To build your message & parse and existing message:

```
var Schema    = require('protobuf').Schema;
var readFile  = require('fs').readFileSync;
var schema = new Schema(readFile(__dirname+'/Voos-message.desc'));
var VooMsg = schema['net.violet.voos.message.VoosMsg'];

// Convert to protobuf format
var msg = VooMsg.serialize({id:1, correlationId: 'hello'});

// Read it back
var outMsg = VooMag.parse(msg);
```

The protobuf library works very well and is easy to use. But if you want a pure JS version, have a look at: [ProtoBufJS](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js)

Comment: what is .desc file? what is net.violet.voos.message.VoosMsg?

Comment: Great Answer! What's the difference between the JS version and the native version? (Performance increases, or what? :P)